# Fancyref with fmtcount

Tags: cross-referencing, varioref, fmtcount, fancyref

When I use `fancyref` with the `vario` package option:

```
\usepackage[vario]{fancyref}
\newcommand{\figvref}[1]{\figurename~\vref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabvref}[1]{\tablename~\vref{#1}}
```

The above would produce a result in such a way that, for example, when referencing a figure (lets say Figure 1) residing on the next page (lets say it is page 3), this would produce the following:

```
"bla bla bla as per Figure 1 on page 3"
```

However, I would like the 'page 3' part of the above to be formatted using the 'fmtcount' package:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\newcommand{\wordnum}[1]{\numberstringnum{#1} (#1)}
```

Insomuch as that the above example should be formatted in the following manner:

```
"bla bla bla as per Figure 1 on page three (3)"
```

Can someone please let me know how to use `fmtcount` within `fancyref`?

Comment: Sorry but why are you using `fancyref` here at all?

Comment: Please give us an MWE rather than asking people to construct one from scratch.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with `refcount` and `fmtcount`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine `\reftextfaraway` using `\vrefpagenum` as detailed in the examples in `varioref`'s manual: `\vrefpagenum{<macro>}{<label>}`. This saves the page number in `<macro>` and can then be used as argument to `fmtcount`'s `\numberstringnum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref,fmtcount}

\renewcommand*\reftextfaraway[1]{%
  \vrefpagenum\fignum{#1}%
  on page \numberstringnum{\fignum}~(\pageref{#1})%
}

\begin{document}

\figurename~\vref{fig:foo}

\newpage
\null\newpage
\null\newpage

\begin{figure}
  \caption{foo bar}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) but, at least when combined with `fancyref`, this gives errors on first compilation.

Comment: @cfr If I use `\usepackage{varioref,fmtcount,fancyref}` (and delete the `aux` file) I don't get any errors. Also not with `\usepackage{fmtcount}\usepackage[vario]{fancyref}`.

Comment: This doesn't work with `\pagenumbering{roman}`, though.

Comment: I get an error if I add a new label with an `\fref{that label}` earlier in the document. The first time I compile after the additions, I get errors. The second time, it is fine as the info is available, I assume.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref,fmtcount}
\usepackage[vario]{fancyref}
\renewcommand*\reftextfaraway[1]{%
  \vrefpagenum\fignum{#1}%
  on page \numberstringnum{\fignum}~(\pageref{#1})%
}

\begin{document}

\Fref{fig:foo} is on a distant page.
% \Fref{sec:asec} is on the same page as \fref{fig:foo}.

\newpage
\null\newpage
\null\newpage

\Fref{fig:foo} is on this page.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{foo bar}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

% \section{sec}\label{sec:asec}

\end{document}` Compile twice. Then uncomment the lines. Compile once -> errors. Compile again -> OK.

Comment: @cfr I only get an error when the referenced label doesn't exist at all. Otherwise it compiles fine (TL2015, updated yesterday).

Comment: Weird. TL 2015. Updated a hour or two ago. (But I kind of doubt anything which is new today is involved.) I'm using `pdflatex` for compilation. I can reproduce the error with both `xelatex` and `lualatex`, though.